# WSL上で走るディストリビューションをそれそれ別々に起動させるには？

Tags: linux, windows-10, wsl

コマンドプロンプト、或いはサードパーティーのコンソールを二つほど開いて各々このコンソールはDebian、このコンソールはKali-Linuxといった感じでピンポイントにディストリを開きたいのですが、どのような方法をとれば良いのでしょうか？一応質問サイトに質問する前にはできる限り調べることが作法なのでQiitaを調べてみると[こちら](https://qiita.com/mizutoki79/items/f6ba08b7f73133102c91)と[こちら](https://qiita.com/chez_sugi/items/fd2e5c39010daa858406)にピンポイントでディストリを開く方法が載っていましたが、私の環境では再現できませんでした。

来年入学が決まった専門学校ではセキュリティに関する授業もあるようなのでWSLはKali-Linuxを使いたいのですが、昔使った感覚では常用には適さないような気がしたのでDebianと同時に開いて使い心地を確かめてみたいと考えています。英語で調べようかと思いましたが、簡単な英語しか読めない上、疲れて眠気が来たのでこちらにポストさせていただきました。

Comment: 複数の異なるディストリビューションを同時に使いたいということであれば WSL でなくて、VirtualBox や VMware、Hyper-V、Vagrant、Docker などの仮想環境の方が便利かもしれません。

Comment: 関連?: [How do you install multiple, separate instances of Ubuntu in WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51584765/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

Comment: Windows 10 のバージョンや WSL のバージョンが古かったりすると、Qiita でお調べになったページのように動作しないことがあります。`winver` コマンドで Windows 10 のバージョン情報、WSL のバージョン情報を一度お調べになってみてはいかがでしょう。

Comment: Kali LinuxはDebianを元にしてセキュリティテスト用に設定したディストリビューションですので、普段使いに向かないのはある意味当たり前なのかなと。ベースは同じわけですから、Debianに必要なパッケージを追加してKali Linuxに近づけることも、その逆も可能ではあります。同時起動については「ダミーの攻撃対象として」等であれば必要性を感じますが、単に使い勝手を比較するだけなら無理する必要はないのかなぁと。